# Проблема с find_package в Visual Studio

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015

Установил vcpkg, с помощью него установил библиотеку GSL. Хочу подключить ее к проекту на CMake, однако выдает ошибку в строке с `find_package()`:

```
CMake Error at CMakeProject1/CMakeLists.txt:17 
(find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GSL" 
with any of the following names:

GSLConfig.cmake
gsl-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "GSL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GSL_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files. If "GSL" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Пробовал указать директорию установленной библиотеки через `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "путь к библиотеке")`, но это тоже не помогает.
Я абсолютный новичок в использовании CMake, подскажите, как всё-таки подключить установленную библиотеку?

Код:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(CMakeProject1)
add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp"     "CMakeProject1.h")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/programming/GitHub/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows")


if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeProject1 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

find_package(GSL CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

Comment: Добавьте код и описание ошибки в виде текста, чтобы вам было проще помочь.

Comment: Подправил вопрос, указав полный текст ошибки. Либо я неправильно прописываю CMakeLists, либо как-то неправильно установил библиотеку...

Comment: Я имел в виду добавить код и ошибку текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Добавил текстом

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решило избавление от `CONFIG REQUIRED` в `find_package()`. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` был обязателен. Как новичок, не смогу объяснить, почему это решило проблему, однако может это поможет кому-то со схожей проблемой.

Надеюсь, кто-то сможет объяснить это явление.